# Finding all sequences in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a big table ( around 500m rows) is SQL server which is as following

```
userId timeStamp action
A      230920323 X1
A      239489349 X2
B      239823788 X2
A      389493849 X3
...
```

I want to find all converted funnels with specific action sequence
In this example the count is 1 which is user A who has X1 X2 X3 in a row
for example i want to find all users who did actions `X1 --> X2 --> X3` in a row

I have a solution which is joining table with itself multiple times. but it's very slow.
Is there any other option for this?

Comment: what is `converted funnels` ? Also please provide more sample data and the correspond required result. And please share your current query / solution

Comment: In the example the count is 1 which is user A who has X1 X2 X3 in a row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `LEAD` and `LAG` analytical functions as follows:

```
select distinct userid from
(select t.*, 
        lead(action) over (partition by userid order by timestamp) as lead_Action,
        lag(action) over (partition by userid order by timestamp) as lag_Action from t)
where lag_Action = 'X1' and action = 'X2' and lead_Action = 'X3';
```